# Ubuntu GNOME Doesn't detect partitions in the installation screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, gnome

Installing: Ubuntu GNOME 3 (16.04)

Problem: Forced into Manual Partitioning mode, (EG I never get the basic options) & No partitions appear within the Boot drive.

How do you fix the fact that the drives aren't showing up? I want to so I can finally finish the install on this. (Been attempting things for 5 days now.)

What I'm seeing between GParted and the Installation screen:
[image: Screen]

```
        Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: msdos
    Disk Flags: 

    Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
     1      32.3kB  53.7GB  53.7GB  primary  ntfs         boot


    Model: ATA WDC WD5000AADS-0 (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: msdos
    Disk Flags: 

    Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
     1      1049kB  105GB  105GB  primary  ntfs
     2      290GB   395GB  105GB  primary  ntfs
     3      395GB   500GB  105GB  primary  ntfs


    Model: ATA WDC WD6400AAKS-2 (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdc: 640GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: msdos
    Disk Flags: 

    Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags


    Model:  Patriot Memory (scsi)
    Disk /dev/sdd: 32.0GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
    Partition Table: msdos
    Disk Flags: 

    Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
     1      1049kB  32.0GB  32.0GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba

Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x011bce22

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       63 104872319 104872257  50G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdcbd8470

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048 204802047 204800000 97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       567037952 771837951 204800000 97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       771837952 976637951 204800000 97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdc: 596.2 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x017fb2ff

Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x011bce22

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       63 104872319 104872257  50G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdcbd8470

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048 204802047 204800000 97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       567037952 771837951 204800000 97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       771837952 976637951 204800000 97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdc: 596.2 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x017fb2ff


Disk /dev/sdd: 29.8 GiB, 32027705344 bytes, 62554112 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00057aba

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *     2048 62554111 62552064 29.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `ext4` partition on any of your drives.  You can boot to the live media and use the `Try Ubuntu` option then run `gparted` so that you can create an `ext4` partition.  Then run the installer from the desktop and install Ubuntu to that partition.  Make two partitions.  One for `ext4` for `/` root. and one for swap.

The `ext4` partition for Ubuntu needs to be at least 8 gigs for the install.  I wol drecommend at least 50 Gigs for the OS so that you can have room to install programs.

You should create a swap partition about 1 1/2 the size of the amount of ram you have to increase performance.

The install steps are located here:
[Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Choose the `Do Somthing Else` option for your install type.

Comment: so make two seperate partitions one named "/" and the other "swap" ? both Ext4?

Comment: Also i have 12gigs of ram so the sizing isn't going to work.

Comment: Yea, It doesn't work more specifically the "Choose the Do something Else" as I mentioned in the question , it skips over that and goes straight to the manual partitioning. and also from this i got Make a Main partition specifically for GNOME in Ext4 then launch the installer and add the next two from that, Doesn't work doesn't detect i have the same screen as in the pictures with the GNOME partition added.